# Spark Streaming Model Overwrite

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

This so straightforward question. How can I save my updated model with the same name to same directory.

`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: path file:/home/mali/model/UpdatedmyRandomForestClassificationModel/data already exists`

There is SaveMode option but I apparently can not use it in 
`model.save(jsc.sc(),"/home/mali/model/UpdatedmyRandomForestClassificationModel");`

Regards..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up first deleting the folder then saving my model. Which is hilariously simple..